# How to get numbers of affected rows in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

Hi I have query like this:

```
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("update Products set amount=? where codebar=? and price=?;");
```

Is any way in sqlite to get number of affected rows? And how can I get it?
Thx

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
  PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement("update Products set amount=? where codebar=? and price=?");
  prest.setDouble(1, 10.00);
  prest.setInt(2, 1);
  prest.setDouble(1, 50.00);
  int rowCount =  prest.executeUpdate();
```

The return value for `executeUpdate()` is an int value that indicates how many rows of a table were updated.

Check following link for more info -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 2):

According to [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29), you can use `executeUpdate()` method to get count of updated rows.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run a select statement before the update to count how many rows match the criteria?

Comment: This won't work for UPDATE queries. The number of rows does not change in this case.